# Highlighting duplicates based on data within the same column

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, duplicates

I'm trying to create a macro that searches the B column to find duplicates of the same string, and then highlights said duplicates from columns A to I

I've managed to create something that highlights the correct cells but does not seem to be able to find the duplicates. Not entirely sure where I've gone wrong but I think it could be because I'm adapting a former macro that looked across two sheets

Code:

```
Sub Duplicate()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, i As Long, j As Long
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
For i = 1 To w1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = w1.Range("B" & i)
    For j = 1 To w1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = w1.Range("B" & j)
        Set rng3 = w1.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 9))
        If StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            rng3.Interior.Color = RGB(168, 188, 255)
        End If
        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I see one problem, you are referring to Activecell, However you never activate or select any cell nor range. This makes the color change on a cell that you have selected when running the macro and no other. If you replace activecell.row with variable i the macro should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting `rng3` to the same cells, because you never change the active cell. Also, you don't really need to have an extra range because you are already looping through the cells.

```
Sub Duplicate()

 Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, i As Long, j As Long
 Dim w1 As Worksheet
 Set w1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 For i = 1 To w1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = w1.Range("B" & i)
    For j = 1 To w1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If j <> i Then
          Set rng2 = w1.Range("B" & j)
          If StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
             rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(168, 188, 255)
             rng2.Interior.Color = RGB(168, 188, 255)
          End If
          Set rng2 = Nothing
        End If
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Will this not colour the entire row though? I only want to colour the cells up to row I

Actually in practice this just highlights column B, which I guess actually makes sense looking back at the macro

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be within VBA? The conditional formatting feature in Excel can do this without having to rely on a macro. This should also refresh faster than running the VBA. For this you have to rely on relative references within the conditional formatting, which are relative to the activecell at the time you set up the rule.

1. Select your data from A:I
2. Conditional formatting> new rule
3. Select 'use a formula to determine which cells to format'
4. Use the formula `=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$B1)>1`, replacing the first variable with your entire range in column B. The single dollar sign on reference `$B1` is very important as it tells it to check column B regardless of which column the formatting is being applied to.

Comment: This will be run in conjunction with a series of other macros, with the idea in mind of eliminating as many clicks as possible from the current system, so ideally I'd prefer it to run within a VBA macro

Comment: @Chris Ok. But if you use native XL functionality then you won't even need a single click to start the macro... clicks=eliminated!